# html form submission on different browsers

Tags: html, forms, browser

I have this form set up to submit some text, the code below works perfectly for chrome, it allows the form to be submitted by pressing enter or clicking the button, but in firefox clicking the button or pressing enter does nothing,

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="main_results.php">
    <input name="q" type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>" size="67"/>
    <input class="submit" type="button" value="Search" onclick="chkChecks()" />
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: can you post chkChecks() js code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`

Comment: He can use button certainly on a condition he sets a name on the `type=button`

Comment: @ZoltanToth naming a button and using 
`if(isset($_POST['button_name']) {
//execute
}`

Comment: Mr.Alien The form is not being submitted with just a named `button`, so you'll never get to the page where you can check if `$_POST['button_name']` set or not. It has to be a `submit`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change type="button" to type="submit"
I also would the php code (`<php echo ($ _GET ['q']);?>`) add htmlspecialchars (`<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']); ?>`) to make it safer.

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/lukas2012/Nj8HK/